# Jquery Onclick Event function not working 2nd time

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html5-canvas, onclicklistener

This is the function I'm using to add an Image and a close button(with the event listener)

```
function loadframe(img, imgid) {

    li = '';
    li += '<li><img src="' + img + '" width="100" height="120" /></li>';
    //li +='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removeajax(\''+img+'\','+imgid+')" >Close</a>';
    li += '<input type="button"  id="activate' + imgid + '" value="close">';

    document.getElementById('ulimage2').innerHTML += li;

}​
```

I'm clicking on some images and they are loaded into the preview pane with 
close button..

I'm calling this function here..
it contains a function called

```
$('#activate' + imgid).click(function() {
    //alert(imgid)
    var yoda1 = stage.get("#" + imgid);
    layery.remove(yodaGroup1);
    layery.draw();
});​
```

Here is the full function..

```
function initStage1(images, imgid) {
    //    alert(imgid)
    var yodaGroup1 = "yodaGroup1" + imgid;
    yodaGroup1 = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: 100,
        y: 110,
        draggable: true,
        name: imgid
    });

    layery.add(yodaGroup1);
    stage.add(layery);
    var yoda1 = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: images.yoda1,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 100,
        height: 120,
        id: imgid,
        name: "image",
        detectionType: "Pixel"
    });

    $('#activate' + imgid).click(function() {
        //alert(imgid)
        var yoda1 = stage.get("#" + imgid);
        layery.remove(yodaGroup1);
        layery.draw();
    });

    yodaGroup1.add(yoda1);
    yodaGroup1.on("dragstart", function() {

        yodaGroup1.moveToTop();
        layery.draw();
    });
    yodaGroup1.on("dblclick dbltap", function() {
        layery.remove(yodaGroup1);
        layery.draw();
    });
    yodaGroup1.on("dragend", function() {
        layery.draw();
        yoda1.saveImageData();
    });
    addAnchor(yodaGroup1, 0, 0, "topLeft");
    addAnchor(yodaGroup1, 100, 0, "topRight");
    addAnchor(yodaGroup1, 100, 120, "bottomRight");
    addAnchor(yodaGroup1, 0, 120, "bottomLeft");

    stage.draw();
    yoda1.saveImageData();
}​
```

This onclick is working for the last uploded image only..
or if I add just one image and then remove it..It is working fine..
If I add more then 1 image it only works for the close button of the last uploded images..
I'm using kineticjs here for HTML5 canvas functionality

Comment: have you tried using `on()` instead of `click()`? perhaps you are binding events to elements before they exist.

Comment: Did  you wrap your entire script in `$(document).ready(function () {`?

Comment: Still not working..Maybe because I'm creating a dynamic close function the event action gets attached to the last uploaded ..pic/close button? Not sure

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your yoda variable outside the function, because when you remove your layer variable, you´re also removing the yoda variable along with it´s events.

Comment: THe onclick is not able to go inside the function itself..SO I don't think it's anything related to the variable inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has to do something with a dom recreation, try changing your `click()` function for `on()` :

```
$('body').on('click','#activate' + imgid,function() {
    //alert(imgid)
    var yoda1 = stage.get("#" + imgid);
    layery.remove(yodaGroup1);
    layery.draw();
});
```